# Name of the formula for divisibility of factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology, divisibility, factorial, mathematical-french

Suppose we want to find how many factors of $7$ is in $500!$.

We want to find number of factors of $7$ in $N = 500 \cdot 499 \cdot ... \cdot 7 \cdot ... \cdot 2 \cdot 1.$ Of course, we can eliminate all factors which are not dividible by $7$, for example $500, 499, 498$. Knowing property of multiplication we infact must find how many seven's are in
the list
$\{7 \cdot 1, 7 \cdot 2, ..., 7 \cdot 71\}.$ Obviously $71$ for the *first hand*. After that, we are finding number of seven's in the $\{7 \cdot 1, ..., 7 \cdot  10\}.$ Obviously there are $10$ seven's in it for the *second hand*. Finally we got number of seven's from $1$ to $10$ which is $1$.

The total number is $71 + 10 + 1= 82.$

Therefore, $N = k \cdot 7^{82},$ where $k > 1$ is not divisible by $7.$

More simply,
$\lfloor\frac{500}{7}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{500}{7^2}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{500}{7^3}\rfloor = 82,$ and simillary for any case.

I don't remember how is this formula called.  (I think it's named after some French mathematician.)  Please help me with this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Comment: Ah, yes - Legendre! Thanks

Comment: It is also called de Polignac's Formula.

Comment: @peter.petrov , you may want to post that as an answer.